# JQuery hide not working - Squarespace 7.1

Tags: jquery, squarespace

This is a simple test to hide paragraph text when an "a" element is clicked.
I am injecting this code into an individual page's header (Squarespace 7.1)
I included the jquery script. Didn't know if I needed it because it is also in the overall custom css for the entire site. When I click the "a" element the page reloads and the p text remains visible.

The URL is https://www.thesquaresandbox.com/hide-object

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("a").click(function(){
  $("p").hide();
});
 
});
</script>
```

Comment: Yes it does work, but your page reloads right after. If you inspect the `a` element, you will notice that `href` is empty. so in your jquery do `$("a").click(function(e){e.preventDefault();$("p").hide();});`